# Error in launching IE with Python-Selenium while the exact same script works fine with Java-Selenium

Tags: java, python, selenium, internet-explorer, automated-tests

I get the following error when I try to launch the Internet explorer using Selenium.

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Ie('C:\\workspace\\IEDriverServer.exe')
driver.get("http://wwww.facebook.com")
```

The error I get is

```
Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. 
Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. 
Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.
```

Combination that does not work: Python/PyCharm while the combination that works : Java/Eclipse

IE explorer driver is the same single file in both cases. It is on same PC

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski added code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell the IE driver to ignore the protected mode settings.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
caps['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True

driver = webdriver.Ie('C:\\workspace\\IEDriverServer.exe', capabilities=caps)
driver.get("http://wwww.facebook.com")
```